# Showing hidden view is very slow

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, swift4

As per these SO threads, I know UI components should be updated through Main UI thread, however I am still unable to resolve issue. My hidden view still shows after more than 20 seconds. Really slow!

[iOS SWIFT Showing hidden view really slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38057233/ios-swift-showing-hidden-view-really-slow)

[Swift/iOS : UIPicker display is not refreshed until tapped after changing the datasource programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45221065/swift-ios-uipicker-display-is-not-refreshed-until-tapped-after-changing-the-da)

To elaborate more, here is what I am doing:

**ViewController**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

  let campusTapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleCampusOpenTap))

        campusTapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1 // Default
        campusSelect.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        campusSelect.addGestureRecognizer(campusTapGesture)

  let networkController = NetworkController()
        networkController.fetchCampusList(empId: empId, terminal: "IOS-011", handler: self)
}
```

While `campusSelect` is `UIView` and tapping on it will show hidden view.

My `NetworkController` has a protocol method `func onCampusResponseSuccess(response: CampusListResponse)` which my `ViewController` conforms in that way:

```
func onCampusResponseSuccess(response: CampusListResponse) {

    let listOfCampus = convertToCampusListModel(apiResponse: response)
    campusPickerData = CampusPickerData(list: listOfCampus)

    // Below code block is performed on main thread because this method runs on background thread and only being invoked when list is received from API
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.campusPick.dataSource = self.campusPickerData
        self.campusPick.delegate = self.campusPickerData
        self.selectedCampus.text = listOfCampus[0].description
    }

    campusResponseException = false
    campusResponseFail = false

    hideAlert(alert: progressAlert)

}
```

When I tap on `campusSelect` UIView, it seems like app is on sleep mode and takes more than 20 seconds to show hidden view and same goes for hiding it.

This is my Gesture Tap:

```
@objc func handleCampusOpenTap(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
      self.campusContainer.isHidden = false
    }
}
```

And this is the action of a button that is used to hide UIView

```
@IBAction func doneCampusSelectClick(_ sender : UIButton){
    let campus = campusPickerData.campusList[campusPick.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)].description

    selectedCampus.text = campus
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
      self.campusContainer.isHidden = true
    }
}
```

What I am doing wrong! My UIPickerView is displayed in hidden view. Is it because of I have custom class for UIPickerView's `dataSource` and `delegate` or is it related to `Threading`?

Just for more clarity, here is my NetworkController's method:

```
let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: {data, response, error in
        guard error == nil else{
            handler.onCampusResponseFail()
            return
        }

        guard let data = data else {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                handler.onCampusResponseException()
            }
            return
        }

        do {
            let jsonDecoder = JSONDecoder()

            let campusListResponse = try jsonDecoder.decode(CampusListResponse.self, from: data)

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                handler.onCampusResponseSuccess(response: campusListResponse)
            }

        } catch let error {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                handler.onCampusResponseException()
            }
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    })
    task.resume()
```

Sorry for lengthy post!

Comment: In Xcode 9 , if something related to ui, updates in background or in different thread rather than main thread , Xcode compiler gives you a blue color thread exception with proper mentioning that 'particular element should be updated only in main thread'. However you application will run fine. Now if you are not getting any exception like this that means your UI updating code is correct. and there must be some problem in your custom UI.

Comment: @ArunKumar Thanks! Can it be the issue of Simulator? Because I am testing ion the simulator. Also, I didn't have custom view. It is just simple **UIView->UIPickerView**.

Comment: Changing the `.isHidden` property of your view in either `handleCampusOpenTap()` or `doneCampusSelectClick()` should *already* be on the main thread. Maybe wrapping those in `DispatchQueue.main.async{}` ***is*** what's causing the problem. Try it without the wrappers, and see what happens.

Comment: @DonMag I have tried both of them. Same issue.

Comment: OK - well, there's no inherent reason for a delay when setting `.isHidden`. I'd suggest simplifying your code to try and narrow-down the possible cause. I'm assuming the data in your `UIPickerView` is being populated correctly? If so, start with a button tap doing nothing but toggling the `.isHidden` property of your view. If you still see the delay, try temporarily moving the picker out of the view, and see what happens. If possible, create a new, basically-the-same project that reproduces the delay, and post it for someone else to look at.

Comment: @DonMag I am suspecting the same. I guess it is UIPicker's data source which is causing problem. Thanks for suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly hide and show the view in main thread i.e.,

//for hiding

```
@objc func handleCampusOpenTap(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
   DispatchQueue.main.async {
     self.campusContainer.isHidden = false
   }
}
```

Also for showing,

```
@IBAction func doneCampusSelectClick(_ sender : UIButton){
    let campus = campusPickerData.campusList[campusPick.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)].description

    selectedCampus.text = campus
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
      campusContainer.isHidden = true
    }
}
```

Hopefully it will help, as rest of code is preety fine.

Comment: I have tried this already, but still unable to fix it. Same issue.

Comment: Try this:-
`DispatchQueue.main.async {
       self.campusContainer.isHidden = false
       self.view.bringSubview(toFront: campusContainer)
    }`